# what is the correct way to pass values to properties?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, reference, uiviewcontroller

i have problems with a really basic thing. setting properties after instantiation a UIViewController-

```
header.h

IBOutlet UITextField *actionLocationFld;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *actionLocationFld;


main.h

@synthesize actionLocationFld;

(void)loadSocialActionView:(id)sender
{
    self.socialActionView = [[SocialActionViewController alloc] init];
    self.socialActionView.actionLocationFld.text = @"test";
    [self.view addSubview:self.socialActionView.view];
}
```

actionLocationFld is a UITextfield. i try to set the text value after instantiation but it does not work. it looks so easy but i can´t figure out. what do i wrong?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i´ve solved it not by adding another property and passing it the value. it seems it is not possible to access the text property of an UITextfield by the way i tried. here´s the new code line

```
   self.socialActionView.address = @"test";
```

inside of my viewcontroller i pass the value forward to self.view.actionLocationFld.text

Answer (score 1):

This may happen because actionLocationFld isn't initialized.

Try to call functions in this order:

```
        self.socialActionView = [[SocialActionViewController alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:self.socialActionView.view];
        self.socialActionView.actionLocationFld.text = @"test";
```

Comment: it did not work either. but i´ve solved it now by adding another property instead of trying to set the text property of an UI element.

Comment: @rockstarberlin That...doesn't really make any sense.  How are you displaying the text if not through a UI element?

Comment: did not say i don´t display it. but i set another property and within viewDidLoad i set the text of the UITextfield with the value of self.address. it works now. even without instantiation of actionLocationFld